# How do i Get values from text fields in AngularJs using track by $index

Tags: angularjs

Right ... In my controller i have an array like this :

```
$scope.EmployeeTimes = [{Day: 'Monday',StartTime: '08:00', FinishTime: '5:00'},
                       { Day: 'Tuesday',StartTime: '08:00', FinishTime: '5:00'},
                       {Day: 'Wed',StartTime: '08:00', FinishTime: '5:00'},
                       {Day: 'Thursday',StartTime: '08:00', FinishTime: '5:00'}]
```

and then i'm passing and looping through the above context in my view like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="a in EmployeeTimes track by $index">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="a.Day">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="a.StartTime">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="a.Finish">
                </div>
```

As you can see im using track by $index and this automatically created the all the text-fields that i need. 
Now how would i get the each value from text-field? so in my case above how i need to get the StartTime and finishTime from Monday - Thursday for a given employee. How would go about getting these values? 
Basically I'm trying to avoid me  creating a startTIme and FinishTime textBox through Monday - Thursday hence why i'm using track index. How can i go about achieving this?

Comment: Just use `$scope.EmployeeTimes[yourIndex].StartTime`

Comment: sorry could you please elaborate more?  i don't get the part you say [yourIndext]  Thank you

Comment: You specify the index you want of the `EmployeeTimes` array - example if you want the first entry, use `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [CodePen with a working example](http://codepen.io/gregori/pen/LNovLK) based on your code: change the content, press the 'process data' link, and look at your console.

Thanks to the Angular binding your Javascript model is updated as soon as you change the content in the text field. If you want to access Monday's starttime you do this:

```
    $scope.EmployeeTimes[0].StartTime
```

You can change the time and then click process; if you look at the console, you will see the updated data in your controller. In the console, I see the following after changing the StartTime on Tuesday to '02:00':

```
    Processing...
    console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 Day: Monday StartTime: 08:00 FinishTime: 5:00
    console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 Day: Tuesday StartTime: 02:00 FinishTime: 5:00
    console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 Day: Wed StartTime: 08:00 FinishTime: 5:00
    console_runner-d0a557e….js:1 Day: Thursday StartTime: 08:00 FinishTime: 5:00
```

This is the function called by the 'process' link:

```
$scope.go = function() {
    console.log('Processing...');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.EmployeeTimes.length; i++) {
      console.log('Day: '+$scope.EmployeeTimes[i].Day+' StartTime: '+$scope.EmployeeTimes[i].StartTime+' FinishTime: '+$scope.EmployeeTimes[i].FinishTime);
    }
```

Comment: idk how i could thank you for this but Thank you so very much ! this is exactly what i needed .. I really appreciate it